# Перетаскивание файла средством Drag & Drop

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно написать программу, в которой выбранный для просмотра текстовый файл нужно будет перетащить в окно Memo1, предназначенное для его просмотра, а для выбора файла нужно использовать компоненты DirectoryListBox и FileListBox.

**При перемещении на поле Memo1 должно выскакивать сообщение, что файл успешно перемещен, или наоборот, что файл переместить нельзя.**

Собственно, два вопроса.

1. По каким критериям можно обозначить успешное перемещение файла/невозможность перенести его в поле?
2. Как реализовать вывод сообщения *"Файл перемещен* /*"Файл переместить нельзя"* после попытки добавления файла в поле?

Comment: **Как реализовать вывод сообщения "Файл перемещен /"Файл переместить нельзя" после попытки добавления файла в поле?**
думаю, расширение файла нужно проверить (запретить к jpg,bmp,mp3,etc)

Comment: Вообще это вздор. "Таскаемость" источника можно и нужно проверять до начала перетаскивания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так попробовать:

```
procedure dragfile(FilePath: string);
var
  MyFile: TextFile;

  function trytoopen: boolean;
  begin
   if Copy(FilePath, Length(FilePath) - 4, Length(FilePath)) = '.txt' then
     try
       AssignFile(MyFile, FilePath);
       result:= true;
     except
       result:= False;
     end;

begin
  ...
  if trytoopen(FilePath) then
    begin
      Reset(MyFile);
      ShowMessage('Файл перемещен');
    end
  else
    ShowMessage('Файл переместить нельзя');
  ...
end;
```